# Error running sfdx force:package:version:create

Tags: community, salesforcedx, unlocked-package

I get an error when I'm trying to create a package version.
This is the command which I'm running:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p assured-pkg4 -d force-app -k 12345 --wait 10 -v DevHub
```

And this is the error that I get:

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  oliver: Not available for deploy for this organization,oliver: Communities must be enabled before deploying a Chatter Network Site,oliver_C: You don't have the correct site publisher privileges for this operation Site : oliver, type: Site.com Community(db=C,api=ChatterNetworkPicasso)

Oliver is the community name. DevHub user is an admin user on salesforce prod, it should have permission to deploy communities. I'm also able to push all metadata on a scratch org.

This is my sfdx-project.json file content:

```
{
    "packageDirectories": [
        {
            "path": "force-app",
            "default": true,
            "package": "assured-pkg4",
            "versionName": "ver 1.0",
            "versionNumber": "1.0.0.NEXT"
        }
    ],
    "namespace": "",
    "sfdcLoginUrl": "https://login.salesforce.com",
    "sourceApiVersion": "46.0",
    "packageAliases": {
        "assured-pkg4": "0Ho6F000000Gmm0SAC"
    }
}
```

If you have any clue I will appreciate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package version creation takes place in a scratch org, whose configuration must meet the minimum requirements for your package's metadata in order for it to be deployed there.

You can specify a scratch org definition to the [`force:package:version:create`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_package.htm#!) command with the `-f` argument. You'd do something like this:

```
sfdx force:package:version:create -p assured-pkg4 -d force-app -k 12345 --wait 10 -v DevHub -f config/project-scratch-def.json
```

Then, the version creation org will have the same configuration as your project's regular scratch orgs, allowing your source to be deployed there.

#### Further Packaging Issues

The `Network` and `Community` metadata entities are not packageable in first or second-generation packaging. You will not be able to include them in your package version. See the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/46).